# What is an appropriate way to practice ATC communications?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-training, phraseology

I'm a PPL trainee and I'm looking for a way to improve my radio communication.

---

https://www.liveatc.net/ is a great way to practice but I can't fully understand the conversation between the unit and the aerodrome. If it just had subtitles or general documentation about it, would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Live ATC is an excellent way to listen and get familiar with your local airports procedures. I used to pick out a tail number and then pretended to be that aircraft. When ATC gave instructions, I would say back what I think the response should be.

If there are terms or phrases you don't understand, you should be able to look them up in the [Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/).

ATC and pilots should do their best to use the official phraseology in the glossary. However, the goal of communication on the radio should be clarity. If there is something you want to say but don't know how, just say it plainly without worrying about the 'official' wording.

Comment: Note that the phraseology differs throughout the world. ICAO phraseology is not quite US phraseology is not quite Canadian phraseology. Make sure you're looking at the correct variant; for example, don't rely blindly on the US FAA's resources if you're training for a European PPL!

Comment: Proper phraseology is important, but the over riding intent is clear communication.  Sometimes plain language is the best way to get your point across.  Otherwise you risk sounding like a junior police spokesman trying to use all the right words he was taught in front of news cameras for the first time:  "The perpetrator, um, passed away as a result of, uh... injuries sustained from... the discharge of the responding officer's sidearm..."

Comment: There is a real and tested science behind the recommended phraseology published in the (FAA) AIM for pilots. The order in which words are read back to ATC, syntax, etc. are essential in reducing communication errors. What may seem an unambiguous and clear phrase listening to tapes after a comm related incident, absent the interfering complexities actually existing at the time, distorts how the phase may have been interpreted by a pilot's or controller's brain. So, following the phraseology guidance provided in the AIM (US) is the best way to ensure errors are minimized.

Answer (score 6):

If you use MS Flight Simulator on your computer (which you should be) you should look into [VATSIM](https://www.vatsim.net/), which is a virtual air traffic control system for people who use Flight Simulator online.  A lot of VATSIM controllers are real controllers, and there are all kinds of resources.

Answer (score 4):

To improve your communications you need to **fly**. There's a world of difference between practicing on the ground and actually saying it in the air, when you are Aviating and Navigating, There are times you will sound like Porky Pig on speed which is an unavoidable part of being a student and nothing to worry about.

Don't get me wrong, practice is useful, what I found was that the act of saying was not as important as knowing what to say. For that I built a list of the common calls I was likely to be asked to make and thought about the responses.

Comment: One thing that one can do, though, especially if they have access to someone else who is used to communicating over simplex radio, is to buy (or borrow) a pair of cheap walkie-talkies, and use those to practice the act of *communicating over simplex radio*. I had the advantage myself during radiotelephony class of being used to radio; that allowed me to focus on the aviation-specific parts (phraseology, frequencies, standard transponder codes, ...), which was hugely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What I found helpful was using Anki - a spaced-repetition flashcard learning tool. You can record and add audio to flash cards. So for example, for a flashcard I wrote the context at the top of the flashcard e.g. `IFR Flight - requesting taxi clearance`. The 'back' (answer) of flashcard would be me impersonating (in an audio clip) what should be said `G-HERO, DA62 at Super Flight, with information D, QNH 1009, request taxi`.

You could also set it up so the 'front' of the flashcard is a self-recorded audio clip of the ATC, and the back (answer) is an audio clip of what the correct response is.

As my science teacher taught me at school (and which I have never forgotten) - the best way you learn a skill is to test that skill in its correct context. i.e. for radios, test your knowledge via actually hearing and responding audibly to a prompt. Reading radio textbooks or listening to ATC may help, but actually getting the brain working by practicing an audible response will best train you for real flying.

Comment: Sounds like non-US phraseology, but why would you report QNH to the controller? Information D (which you’ve just reported) should contain the current QNH and if the actual is different the controller should tell you…

Comment: In the UK, in my experience, ATC will tell you the QNH even if you tell them what information X you have copied (unless you tell them what QNH you have copied) E.g. see Pg 99-100 (chapter 4 pg 5).  https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP413%20MAY16.2.pdf

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @Jim UK ATIS quite often reports QNH & QFE, so the point of repeating it in your initial contact is basically telling the controller which you're using.

Comment: @Jamiec - So ATC allows pilots to use what they choose and “converts” their altitude instructions to each pilot’s chosen datum?

Comment: @Jim No conversion is done. I suspect it's just for controller awareness. ie/ if I read back  QFE Im probably staying in the circuit (pattern). But it's all pretty moot as you've probably had to book out and give details of your sortie anyway!

Comment: @Jamiec - Ok thanks. Not having ever operated in a system where that is the case I’m really struggling to see why this complication was ever introduced/condoned/supported.

Comment: @Jamiec I'm not too sure. When operating commercially out of British International Airports I have still been expected to state Information and QNH. These same airports never refer to a QFE. I suspect clarification on QNH is primarily due to the complex layout of Class A-E airspace across large areas of the UK, complex STARs/SIDs and high numbers of civil and military traffic densely compacted into a relatively small area - making correct altimetry incredibly important.

Answer (score 1):

a) Get an airband receiver and listen to ATC whenever you have the opportunity.
b) Armchair flying and self-talk ... sounds funny but does work extremely well!